# Routing with lazyLoading in children not working - cannot match route

Tags: angular

This is my app-setup:

[image]

This is my **app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { SoftwareComponent } from './components/software/software.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        outlet: 'main',
        component: SoftwareComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'personal',
                children: [
                    {
                        path: '',
                        loadChildren: './components/software/data/personal/personal.module#PersonalModule' 
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }   
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {enableTracing: true})],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

My Error is:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'personal'
>   Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'personal'

Maybe someone can tell whats wrong with my setup?

Comment: Did you try `routerLink=['/personal']` ?

Comment: nope, give me a second

Comment: You have 2 reference to the path `path: ''`

Comment: Doesn't work kris, and Jonas Praem the first empty path is the main-route and the other empty path are the child-routes - i think there isn't any error if you follow the official docs -> https://angular.io/guide/router#child-routing-component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `personal` on the same level as the first `''`.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: 'personal'
    },
    {
        path: 'personal',
        outlet: 'main',
        component: SoftwareComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                loadChildren: './components/software/data/personal/personal.module#PersonalModule' 
            },
            {
                path: '',
                loadChildren: './components/software/header/header-personal/header-personal.module#HeaderPersonalModule'
            }
        ]
      }
    }   
];
```

Comment: If i copy it as you posted, i get a blank white page. If i than edit your `redirectTo: personal` to `redirectTo: /personal` i get the same error like everytime, cannot match any route.

Comment: If i remove the `outlet`, i'm navigated to `localhost:4200/personal` but also: Blank white page

Comment: You need the `<router-outlet>` in order for Angular to know where to load the components. Remove the `children` and confirm that `SoftwareComponent` is loading before continuing.

Comment: removed `name="main"` from my `<router-outlet>` inside `app.component.ts` now the app gets loaded, but if i click on the link, no module is rendered inside my content. If i than pass the name, of the outlet, in which i want the `PersonalComponent` to be rendered, i'm encountering https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12842 - seems like i'm running in a bunch of bugs

Comment: Usually, I wouldn't use `{ path: '', loadChildren: '...' }` in that way. I'd use `{ path: 'personal', loadChildren: '...' }` and then inside the lazy-loaded module, I'd put `{ path: '', component: '...' }`.

Comment: My problem is, that i need to load two modules at the same path. And i think it's not good to have twice the same path?!

Comment: Okay so now the content is working and gets shown, but the header isn't shown, although he's nearly a copy of the function from the `PersonalComponent`. Maybe this could no be a problem with two `<router-outlets>` on the same level? I named booth but only the content gets rendered correctly

Comment: If the header is something that should be on all pages, then it should be part of `AppModule` (and inside `app.component.html`).